# JavaScript map containing arrays turns into map containing maps

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, gson

I am creating a map containing arrays. 
I'm sending this map as parameter to a method in a popup window.

This map of arrays is turning into a map of maps in the popup window!!

Im using IE8.

I'm creating a map like this:

```
var mapDetails = new Object();
mapDetails.fields = ['A','B'];
mapDetails.optSampleData = ['X','Y'];
```

JSON of map Im sending:

```
{'fields':['A','B'],'optSampleData':['X','Y']}
```

JSON of map Im receiving:

```
{'fields':{'0':'A','1':'B'},'optSampleData':{'0':'X','1':'Y'}}
```

This wouldnt be a problem in JS as the data can still be accessed as fields[0]. But, I'm sending it to server-side where I'm using GSON to parse the JSON. GSON turns it into a map.

Comment: How exactly you are "sending this map as parameter to a method in a popup window"? Do you use JSON serialization to string? If "yes" then what exactly is used?

Comment: I pass this object as a parameter to a function in the popup window. And then forward the same to server-side using JQuery ajax (to servlet). If sent from the main window the data gets converted to Map containing Lists by GSON. From the popup window it gets converted to a Map containing Maps by GSON. So, I tried to trace step by step using JSON.stringify. In the main page (before method call) stringify shows map containing arrays and in the popup window (on receiving method parameter) it shows map containing maps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
function myParser(str) {

    str = str.replace(/'/g, '"');
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);

    for(var item in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            var array = [];
            for(var arrItem in obj[item]) {
                if(obj[item].hasOwnProperty(arrItem)) {
                    array.push(obj[item][arrItem]);
                }
            }
            obj[item] = array;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

You can pass the received string into this function and receive your desired map containing arrays

Also you can reform your received string into your desired string format by this function:

```
var str = "{'fields':{'0':'A','1':'B'},'optSampleData':{'0':'X','1':'Y'}}";
var obj = myParser(str);
var desiredFormat = JSON.stringify(obj);
/* The result would be: */ 
/* "{"fields":["A","B"],"optSampleData":["X","Y"]}" */
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I want to know the root cause because I intend to use JSON/GSON heavily and I dont want any surprises. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Teddy Can you provide more codes? for example codes for how you pass the object from main window to popup window, Or create a fiddle!